# How to compute False Accept and False reject rates using one class SVM Python

Tags: one-class-classification

How to compute False Accept and False reject rates using one class SVM? I have a user data with around 70000 samples. I am trying to apply one class SVM here. The number of -1 values obtained are 12765 and the rest are displayed as 1. From these values obtained, how do I compute False Accept Rate ?

Answer (score 1):

You can compute it with the help of [Confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix).

```
FAR = FPR = FP/(FP + TN)

FRR = FNR = FN/(FN + TP)

where FP: False positive
      FN: False Negative
      TN: True Negative
      TP: True Positive
```

You can also find the original answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272962/are-far-and-frr-the-same-as-fpr-and-fnr-respectively)

Comment: I understand the formula to compute FAR and FRR and have tried it using binary classifiers. But my question is how do I compute it in one-class classifier ? As mentioned I have number of  '-1' values as12000 and the remaining 58000 as '+1' values.

Comment: Eg: When you are predicting only "dog class" in your model and if your model *does not* predict correctly, you would still get 2 labels. One for correctly predicting the Dog and the other for predicting it Falsely. Therefore there wouldn't be such thing as a one-class classifier. The single class implies that the answer is always 1 but we shouldn't leave the fact that the answer is not 1.